# Reading packet content in linux kernel (netfilters)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, firewall, packet-sniffers

I'm building a simple linux firewall, implemented as a kernel module using netfilters. I want it to be able to do Deep Packet Inspection, and for that I need to be able to read the content of the packet. How would I go on doing that?

Comment: I have borrowed @sam-protsenko 's answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data) to answer your question. Thankyou sam you smashed that one.

Answer (score 0):

From the netfilter website.

> netfilter is a set of hooks inside the Linux kernel that allows kernel
>   modules to register callback functions with the network stack. A
>   registered callback function is then called back for every packet that
>   traverses the respective hook within the network stack.

**Step 1 :**

Write a module for deep packet inspection. Linux tcp api will help you do so.
See the accepted answer to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data) which will help you get started. In that you might wish to remove :

```
/* Show only HTTP packets */
    if (user_data[0] != 'H' || user_data[1] != 'T' || user_data[2] != 'T' ||
            user_data[3] != 'P') {
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }
```

just in case you wish to deal with all the packets.

**Step 2 :**

Implement a hook for the above module in the kernel using netfilter.