# Difference between skb_header_pointer and skb_transport_header?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm trying to implement a netfilter module, while processing sk_buff I found two possible ways to retrieve TCP header:

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
struct tcphdr *tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
```

And

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = skb_header_pointer(skb, 0, sizeof(struct iphdr), &_iph)
struct tcphdr *tcp_header = skb_header_pointer(skb, ip_header->ihl * 4, sizeof(struct tcphdr), &_tcph);
```

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`ip_hdr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.193/source/include/linux/ip.h#L23) from */include/linux/ip.h* and [`tcp_hdr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.193/source/include/linux/tcp.h#L27) from */include/linux/tcp.h* in case you know that there cannot be [paged-`skb`](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html) here:

```
struct iphdr *ip_header = ip_hdr(skb);
if (ip_header->protocol == IPPROTO_TCP) {
    struct tcphdr *tcp_header = tcp_hdr(skb);
    //...
```

---

`skb_header_pointer()` should be used in case the appearance of paged-`skb` is possible. Examples: [IP](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_conntrack_l3proto_ipv4.c#L39), [TCP](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c#L395), [ICMP](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/net/ipv4/icmp.c#L628), etc.
So if the header is in paged data (fully or partially) - `skb_header_pointer()` will correctly handle it.
Also remember to **check the return value** of `skb_header_pointer()`, it can return NULL.

Useful links: [1](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/labs/networking.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data)