# Can't get data (payload) from sk_buff

Tags: c, tcp, linux-kernel, hook, netfilter

I try to create a module for encrypt network packets but when try get data from **sk_buff** and print it in Hexa not get a correct packet.
I use this method to print data in Hexa :

```
void pkt_hex_dump(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    size_t len;
    int rowsize = 16;
    int i, l, linelen, remaining;
    int li = 0;
    uint8_t *data, ch;

    printk("Packet hex dump:\n");
    data = (uint8_t *) skb_mac_header(skb);

    if (skb_is_nonlinear(skb)) {
        len = skb->data_len;
    } else {
        len = skb->len;
    }

    remaining = len;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += rowsize) {
        printk("%06d\t", li);

        linelen = min(remaining, rowsize);
        remaining -= rowsize;

        for (l = 0; l < linelen; l++) {
            ch = data[l];
            //data[l] = '1';
            printk(KERN_CONT "%02X ", (uint32_t) ch);
        }
        data += linelen;
        li += 10;

        printk(KERN_CONT "\n");
    }
}
```

I used this [sample](https://github.com/abhishekkushwaha4u/Simple-Chat-app-in-python) to create a chat application.

And `output` when I send `hello world` message from client to server is :

```
[ 3981.963124] Packet hex dump:
[ 3981.963125] 000000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 45 00
[ 3981.963128] 000010   00 34 6A 1F 40 00 40 06 D1 A2 7F 00 01 01 7F 00
[ 3981.963130] 000020   00 01 07 E4 BD 36 A2 52 E9 62 6D 40 3D FE 80 10
[ 3981.963133] 000030   02 00 FF 28
```

## And I try to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data) but can't get any output.

## My hook function

```
static unsigned int hfunc( void *priv, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct nf_hook_state *state){

    struct iphdr *iph;          /* IPv4 header */
    struct tcphdr *tcph;        /* TCP header */
    uint16_t sport;
    uint16_t dport;
    struct ethhdr *ether = eth_hdr(skb);


    iph = ip_hdr(skb);          /* get IP header */
    tcph = tcp_hdr(skb);        /* get TCP header */
    sport = ntohs(tcph->source);
    dport = ntohs(tcph->dest);

      /* Watch only port of interest */
    if (dport == PTCP_WATCH_PORT || sport == PTCP_WATCH_PORT){



    printk(KERN_INFO "UDP packet is received: {'sport': %d; 'dport': %d}\n", sport, dport);



   printk("Source: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", ether->h_source[0], ether->h_source[1], ether->h_source[2], ether->h_source[3], ether->h_source[4], ether->h_source[5]);
   printk("Destination: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", ether->h_dest[0], ether->h_dest[1], ether->h_dest[2], ether->h_dest[3], ether->h_dest[4], ether->h_dest[5]);
   printk("Protocol: %d\n", ether->h_proto);


    pkt_hex_dump(skb);

    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Comment: From where `pkt_hex_dump()` is invoked? Please provide more details. Did you interested in TCP payload or IP payload or the payload of Ethernet frame?

Comment: @red0ct sorry, but I still a beginner if you help me to understand the difference between payload type.

Comment: Do you familiar with the basics of networking? Did you hear about [protocol encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking))? Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-ip-model/)

Comment: @red0ct thank you for supporting, and I add my hook function , I just need to get hello world message and encrypt it.

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve Ethernet header? Where exactly your hook is registered? See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg). It's still absolutely unclear how you are trying to "embed" in kernel. P.S. looks like homework.. it's difficult to imagine the circumstances under which you need to manually encrypt data from within the kernel.